# Start "Setup.exe" with mono or define drive_c

Tags: wine, mono, dotnet

I try to install a Windows program on Ubuntu. This program needs .NET40.

Afaik I have two options:

1. I use `wine`, install `winetricks` and with `winetricks dotnet40` and everything with win32-architecture (because dotnet40 only installs on 32bit). After successful installation via `wine Setup.exe` and trying to start the application with `wine Program.exe` I get strange error boxes so I tried the second way.
2. I install mono.

   1. If I try to call `mono Setup.exe` I'll get:

      ```
      Cannot open assembly 'Setup.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
      ```

      and somewhere else I read that it isn't possible to run setups with mono. **Is there a way to run the setup with mono?**
   2. I call `Setup.exe` with `wine` which works and afterwards I try to start the installed program with `mono Program.exe`. But now the program doesn't find its required resources. **Is there a possibility to tell mono where the installed files are placed?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to install wine-mono package, and run it with wine.

```
sudo apt-get install wine-mono
wine ./Setup.exe
```

Unless you're developing C# app with GNU/Linux, you'd better to stay away of the `mono` app. There's too many cases where plain `mono` wouldn't work, while the wine does. Often this is caused by .net app usage of some native Windows libraries instead of sticking to C# ones. You could blame the developers, and you would be right, because they have to think next time, and use Qt with C++ at the very least, or something else as flexible and crossplatform. However just to let you know: programing with Windows is a bunch of workarounds, also surprisingly C# was made to accord the old WinAPI *(just wrapped to .net)* instead of fixing its fails.